# Displaying the names and times of the first and second winners of a marathon

Tags: java, arrays

I would like your help here guys

/**
 * In this assignment I am supposed to display the names and times of the first and second winners (2 best times) of a marathon
 * But I am struggling with the second one
 */

```
public class MitAssignment3Chapter7 {
public static void main(String args[]){

    String runners[] = {"Gene","Elvis","Presley","Felicity","Welcome"};
    int[] timeInMinutes = {40,50,76,56,62};

    int index = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int first = timeInMinutes[1];

    for (a = 0 ; a < timeInMinutes.length; a++){
        if ( first > timeInMinutes[a]){
            index = a;
            first = timeInMinutes[index];
        }
       // if (first < timeInMinutes[a] && timeInMinutes[a])  Trying to do the second here
    }
    System.out.println("The winner of the marathon is: "+runners[index]+" with "+timeInMinutes[index]+" minutes");

}
```

}

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `Hashmap`?

Comment: Creativity is welcomed. I am learning java programming at university but this is an assignment from an online MOOC and I want to learn as much as I can so I am open to any idea.

Answer (score 1):

using other collections would be easy.. but you can do it with simple arrays also.. not only second one, you can find all ranks of runners by sorting arrays.. check this code..

```
     public static void main(String args[]) {
        String runners[] = { "Gene", "Elvis", "Presley", "Felicity", "Welcome" };
        int[] timeInMinutes = { 40, 50, 76, 56, 62 };
        int a = 0;
        int tempTime = 0;
        String tempRunner = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < timeInMinutes.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < timeInMinutes.length; j++) {
                if (timeInMinutes[i] > timeInMinutes[j]) {
                    tempTime = timeInMinutes[i];
                    timeInMinutes[i] = timeInMinutes[j];
                    timeInMinutes[j] = tempTime;

                    tempRunner = runners[i];
                    runners[i] = runners[j];
                    runners[j] = tempRunner;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < runners.length; index++)
            System.out.println("Rank " + (index+1) + ": " + runners[index] + " with " + timeInMinutes[index] + " minutes");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the winner first, after you had found out winner, take winner out of your time array and find the fastest people in your current array, it will be the second player.

Comment: Kind of updating the initial Array of runners?

Comment: But what if I was just asked to display the second winner?

Comment: It is what you need. https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/cpp-program-to-find-second-largest-element-in-an-array/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class to hold result time and the name. Implement `compareTo` method for this class. Populate new `List` with all the results and sort the one. Now it's possible to get any `Nth` result(time and name).

```
static class Result implements Comparable<Result> {
    private final int time;
    private final String name;

    Result(int time, String name) {
        this.time = time;
        this.name = name;
    }

    int getTime() { return time; }

    String getName() { return name; }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Result o) {
        return Integer.compare(time, o.time);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    String runners[] = {"Gene","Elvis","Presley","Felicity","Welcome"};
    int[] timeInMinutes = {40,50,76,56,62};

    List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>(runners.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < runners.length; i++) {
        results.add(new Result(timeInMinutes[i], runners[i]));
    }

    Collections.sort(results);

    Result second = results.get(1);
    System.out.println("Second winner: " + second.getName() + "; Time: " + second.getTime());
}
```